# Error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Kinect.dll' or one of its dependencies" in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, kinect-sdk

I wrote a program using kinect SDK v2.0 with wpf.  I added the Microsoft.Kinect.dll in References, but when I run the program I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in test.exe
>   Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Kinect.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Is there a yellow triangle beside your reference? If it's the case, it means that the dll you selected really doesn't exist. It could mean the it has changed path, or version... make sure the path of the dll really exists.

Comment: thank you mgarant. i checked before, Even i delete it and again add Microsoft.Kinect.dll to References with source path. but problem still be.